# how generating wadl for jax-rs is getting 404 status

Tags: jax-rs, wadl

Hi I have rest web services running on tomcat. I'm trying to get wadl generated. What I read is that I just need to type url: `http://ip:8080/application.wadl` and it will be generated. However all I get is 404 status.
If my deployed war name is ABC for example I'm also trying to execute: `http://ip:8080/ABC.wadl`, but again 404.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It really does depends on the framework that is mediating between Tomcat and your implementation classes. For example, with Apache CXF you get the WADL for a service by fetching http://example.com:8080/ABC?wadl (this is in the simplest case where your webapp is deployed as ABC and the root RESTful resource is served by the root of the webapp).